# Append additional HTML result in calling MVC action by Ajax in DNN8

Tags: html, ajax, asp.net-mvc, action

I'm new in DNN development.

I have created a very simple module in Visual studio--- A textbox and a button.

I just want to call the action in a controller by click the button, then show the return result in the textbox.

The code call the action success, but not sure why append lots of HTML inforation in the result.

Here is the action in the controller:

```
public ActionResult test1()
{
    return Content("Return something");
}
```

Here is the Ajax code from the View:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btnSub").click(function () {
        //alert(this.action);
        $.ajax({
            type:"GET",
            contentType:"application/text",
            url: "@Url.Action("test1", "Sky")",
            data:"",
            dataType: "text",

            success: function (data) { $("#txtResult").val(data); alert("Success！") },
            error:function(){alert("Failed!")}
    });
});
});
```

And here is the result show in the textbox:

[image]

Anyone can let me know why the HTML information returned? Actually, I don't need it.

Thanks

Comment: Change it to `return Json("Return something", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);` and use `dataType: 'json',`

Comment: Hi Stephen. Thanks. When I set the  datatype as JSON, the Ajax got the the 200 status, but run the error:function(){alert("Failed!") statement rather than the success: function (data) .

Comment: Did you change it to `dataType: 'json'`?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, as described in DNN8 MVC [unsupported features](http://www.dnnsoftware.com/docs/developers/about-modules/unsupported-mvc-features.html), it's not yet possible to return a JsonResult. So the solution I used is to return an ActionResult (although the function returns Json):

```
public ActionResult Test()
{
    return Json(new { success = true });
}
```

On jquery side, I setup ajax call to receive result as html. This avoid the browser to display a parsing error. Finally, just need to remove the html part and manually parse the response. It's not very clean, but the only solution I found until DNN support JsonResult.

```
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("Index", "Contact")',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'html',
    data: $('#contact-form input').serialize(),
    success: function (response) {
        jsonPart = response.substring(0, response.indexOf("<!DOCTYPE html>"));
        var data = JSON.parse(jsonPart);
        if (data.success) {
            alert("Great");
        }
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert("Error!");
    }
});
```

**EDIT : Improved solution**
DNN8 now support IMvcRouteMapper. You can then register a route in RouteConfig.cs. Once done, you can call the function using following URL :

```
/DesktopModules/MVC/ModuleName/Controller/Action
```

The action can return a JsonResult. But pay attention, if you just call that function, it will fail with a null exception on ModuleContext. You have to include in the ajax call the following header :

```
headers: {
   "ModuleId": @Dnn.ModuleContext.ModuleId,
   "TabId": @Dnn.ModuleContext.TabId,
   "RequestVerificationToken": $("input[name='__RequestVerificationToken']").val()
}
```

You can find the module complete code [here](https://github.com/dnnsoftware/Dnn.Platform.Samples.Mvc).

Answer (score 0):

This is a working ajax call in DNN 9. You dont have to use `@urlaction` it will give whole html as well as data. `dnn.getVar("sf_siteRoot", "/") + 
    "DesktopModules/MVC/ModuleName/Controller/Action",` this does the trick and don't forget to add the header otherwise it will throw 500 error.

```
$.ajax({
url: dnn.getVar("sf_siteRoot", "/") + 
"DesktopModules/MVC/ModuleName/Controller/Action",
type: 'POST',
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
dataType: 'json',
data: "{ 'id':" + JSON.stringify(3543)+" }",
headers: {
            "ModuleId": @Dnn.ModuleContext.ModuleId,
            "TabId": @Dnn.ModuleCon`enter code here`text.TabId,
            "RequestVerificationToken": 
             $("input[name='__RequestVerificationToken']").val()
        },
success: function (response) {
        debugger;
},
error: function (errmsg) {
    alert("Error!");
}
});
```

Your controller should be

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ActionName(int id)
    {            
        var data = id;
        return BuidJsonResult(true,data);
    }
```

Happy Coding :)